# Netbeans compilation error

Tags: java

// I am new to Java and was practicing some questions on netbeans. I get compilation error on  public class bank_acc ( ide is suggesting me to change the name of my whole program to bank_acc but as far as I know the program name is same as the class name which has the main function ). When I change it I get error on class prog2. Either way it's not working out. Please help.

```
package prog2;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class bank_acc{
    String name;
    double acc_no;
    String acc_type;
    double bal;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    void bank_acc(){
        System.out.println("Enter basic values");
        name = s.nextLine();
        acc_no = s.nextInt();
        acc_type = s.nextLine();
        bal = 1000;
    }
    // function to deposit money in acc.
    void deposit(){
        System.out.println("Enter the amount to be deposited");
        double amt=s.nextDouble();
        bal+=amt;
    }
    // function to withdraw amt after checking it.
    void wac(){ 
        System.out.println("Current balance = "+bal);
        System.out.println("Enter amount to be withdrawn");
        Double wdraw_amt=s.nextDouble();
        bal-=wdraw_amt;
    }
    void display(){
        System.out.println("Welcome to THE BANK !");
        System.out.println("Your name is: "+name);
        System.out.println("Account Balance: "+bal);
    }

}
public class Prog2{


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        bank_acc a = new bank_acc();
        a.deposit();
        a.wac();
        a.display();
        System.out.println("Thank you. Keep working!");

    }

}
```

Comment: You have two public classes.  Only one may be public.

Comment: In Java, only one public class can be in Java file and also this class name must be same with file name

Comment: For future reference, if you have an error you are asking about, **tell us what the error is**. Don't make us sit here and guess.

Comment: @tnw - okay. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have only one top level public either class or interface in any java compilation unit ( .java source file ).